# PHP Intelephense Error in Laravel Blade File

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I get this error using thi type of code in my blade file, anyone have a way to remove this error?

[image: enter image description here((https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3ZQo.png)]

the red underline should be gone

Comment: Are you using visual studio code?

Comment: Please don´t add images of code or error messages. Add them as formatted text to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, installing the previous version or slightly older version of the plugin works. Try installing the previous version of PHP Intelephense. Once encountered this on VS Code. All the best.

Comment: i tried install version 1.14, but still get same outcome